# Typo 3 neos Remove link

Tags: neoscms

I want know how to remove the link in backend.[remove link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc5rx.png) I can add link and show it on frontend But i can't remove link. I press remove button, and link don't remove. 
My NodeTypes.yaml code

```
link:
  type: string
  ui:
    label: 'Link'
    inspector:
      editor: 'TYPO3.Neos/Inspector/Editors/LinkEditor'
```

How can I to fix it?

Comment: 1. Check console for javascript errors. 2. Run composer update on your base - I cannot reproduce this bug, so it might have been already fixed.